# Database connectivity issue in Mule4.2.0

Tags: magento2, database

We are facing a  MySQL database connectivity issue in Mulesoft, the mule has two types of database transactions. one is to the mule’s server( Self ) database and the other one is to the remote server database.

Recently we upgraded MyQL 5.7 to 8.0 in the remote server, After that the mule database transaction within the server (Self) is fine and we are facing an issue on the remote server. We checked the log details and it shows like

```
Message               : Cannot get connection for URL jdbc:mysql://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx/{data_base_name}?logger=org.mule.extension.db.api.logger.MuleMySqlLogger : Could not create a connection to database server.
Error type            : DB:CONNECTIVITY
```

In our investigation, we believe that this issue is due to the JDBC driver compatibility issue( Mule 4.2.0 with MySQL 8.0).

Please share your thoughts on this.